# How to use @PostMapping()?

Tags: java, spring

I want to create API call by passing string value but without returning output.

Inside API method, only updating the value to database.

How to create API  @postmapping(value = "endpoint") in this case

Comment: You can try @RequestMapping(value="endpoint", method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: instead of using @RequestMapping(value="endpoint", method=RequestMethod.POST) , we can use @PostMapping(value="endpoint)

Comment: Yes you can but without returning anything how can you be sure whether the transaction is successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not want to return anything? You should return at least `true` to notify the caller that the transaction was successful.

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public boolean updateSomeData(String value) {
    boolean result = someService.updateSomething(value);
    return result;
}
```

If you still do not want to return anything, you can simply change return type of the method to `void` as follows

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public void updateSomeData(String value) {
    someService.updateSomething(value);
}
```

Comment: Okay. But i'm passing string parameters how can i declare it ?

Comment: I just put input type of `Object` because I don't know about your input.

Comment: one parameter updateSomeData(@RequestParam String value)

Comment: Then you can use, 
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public void updateSomeData(String value) {
    someService.updateSomething(value);
}

Comment: @VanithaV I updated my answer. You can simply use `String value`. You can use or emit `@RequestParam`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass string as pathvariable like,

http://your_host:your_port/your_projectName/endpoint/string_value

you can use below code

`@PostMapping(value="/endpoint/{string_value}")
public void update(@PathVariable("string_value") String string_value){
        //update operation
}`

If you want to pass string as requestvariable like,

http://your_host:your_port/your_projectName/endpoint?string_value=somevalue

you can use below code

`@PostMapping(value="/endpoint")
public void update(@RequestParam("string_value") String string_value){
        //update operation
}`